# RDP is being resized after disconnecting from a session?

Tags: rdp, blueprism

I have set up a program in BluePrism that takes a screenshot of a webpage when errors are detected in said webpage. I have everything working as of now, but the only thing that is puzzling me is the window being resized. I have the window set at 1920x1080 when connecting to the RDP, but when I disconnect from the session, the window resizes itself to 1024x968. It would be worth noting that I am using a batch file to disconnect from the session Is there any way to keep the window at 1920x1080 after being disconnected?

Comment: You can fix that by connecting to that machine using non-RDP program, like TightVNC, and changing the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In your process you can make Initial page, that can call your custom object action that can set resolution what you want. I'm use code like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DEVMODE1
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmDeviceName;
    public short dmSpecVersion;
    public short dmDriverVersion;
    public short dmSize;
    public short dmDriverExtra;
    public int dmFields;
    public short dmOrientation;
    public short dmPaperSize;
    public short dmPaperLength;
    public short dmPaperWidth;
    public short dmScale;
    public short dmCopies;
    public short dmDefaultSource;
    public short dmPrintQuality;
    public short dmColor;
    public short dmDuplex;
    public short dmYResolution;
    public short dmTTOption;
    public short dmCollate;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string dmFormName;
    public short dmLogPixels;
    public short dmBitsPerPel;
    public int dmPelsWidth;
    public int dmPelsHeight;
    public int dmDisplayFlags;
    public int dmDisplayFrequency;
    public int dmICMMethod;
    public int dmICMIntent;
    public int dmMediaType;
    public int dmDitherType;
    public int dmReserved1;
    public int dmReserved2;
    public int dmPanningWidth;
    public int dmPanningHeight;
};

class User_32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE1 devMode);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(ref DEVMODE1 devMode, int flags);
    public const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;
    public const int CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY = 0x01;
    public const int CDS_TEST = 0x02;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL = 0;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_RESTART = 1;
    public const int DISP_CHANGE_FAILED = -1;
}

class CResolution
{
    public void ChangeResolution(int a, int b, out bool success, out string message)
    {
        Screen screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        int iWidth = a;
        int iHeight = b;
        DEVMODE1 dm = new DEVMODE1();
        dm.dmDeviceName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmFormName = new String(new char[32]);
        dm.dmSize = (short)Marshal.SizeOf(dm);
        if (0 != User_32.EnumDisplaySettings(null, User_32.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, ref dm))
        {
            dm.dmPelsWidth = iWidth;
            dm.dmPelsHeight = iHeight;
            int iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_TEST);
            if (iRet == User_32.DISP_CHANGE_FAILED)
            {
                success = false;
                message = "Unable to process your request. Description: Unable To Process Your Request. Sorry For This Inconvenience.";
            }
            else
            {
                iRet = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettings(ref dm, User_32.CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY);
                switch (iRet)
                {
                    case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL: 
                        break;
                    case User_32.DISP_CHANGE_RESTART:
                    {
                        success = false;
                        message = "Description: You Need To Reboot For The Change To Happen. If You Feel Any Problem After Rebooting Your Machine Then Try To Change Resolution In Safe Mode.";
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        success = false;
                        message = "Description: Failed To Change The Resolution.";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        success = true;
        message = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Use standart resolutions such as 1024x768, 1280x800, 1280x1024, 1360x768, 1366x768, 1400x1050, 1440x900, 1600x900, 1680x1050, 1920x1080.

I call it in such way:

[image]

[image]